# size issues with Siemens PN series load centers

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I'm considering updating my 20-space/40-circuit Siemens load center (1987 vintage) to a 30-space/48-circuit panel.

Looking at the Siemens offerings in the "plug-on neutral" PN series, I'm noting that the likely panel (model# PN3048B1200C) is only 30" high.  This is the same height as my existing panel, yet it has 10 more spaces, meaning the vertical columns of breakers are 5" taller.   Seems to me things could get a mite crowded.

I also notice that the "outdoor" version of the same panel (model# PNW3048B1200C) is 35" high, thus allowing the same amount of spaciousness as my existing panel.

So, I'm wondering WHY the outdoor panel is taller ?  It simply has the NEMA 3R enclosure, but no additional wiring or hardware, so why ?   Secondly, is there any reason I shouldn't use the taller "outdoor" panel even though my panel location is indoors ?

Here is the catalog (Im looking at page 5 of the catalog, which is page 7 of the PDF) ...

https://cache.industry.siemens.com/dl/files/752/109793752/att_1054903/v1/SIE_SA_ResiLoadcenters.pdf

... and here are drawings of the two panels (sorry I can't figure out how to put them side-by-side) ...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're really not going to have a problem, unless you put the panel together sloppy. Panels are required to be large because of *wire bending space* rules.

If you're getting cramped, look at how you are laying the cables in the box. There should be layers. The back layer should be all the ground wires, which should go to the ground bar and then be pushed into the absolute back of the box.  The next layer should be neutral wires that don't need to go to AFCI/GFCI.  The next layer is hots (and neutrals to AFCI/GFCI).

It's best to cut all wires (but ground) long enough to reach any breaker space in the panel.  For neatness sake, fly past the breaker you want then double back. It also helps for wires coming in the top to go to bottom breakers, and wires coming in the bottom to go to top breakers.  In between one of these layers is the service wires.

---

The difference in height for indoor/outdoor panels is a couple of things.  First, they need more room at the bottom for side and bottom cable entrances, because top cable entrances are not allowed in outdoor panels.   (This is another reason not to use the outdoor version of the panel for your indoor application, since you probably have branch circuits coming in from both above and below, and there are no knockouts on the top of the outdoor panel, just the hub opening).

Second, with an indoor panel, the factory answer for a bottom cable entry is to invert the panel with the main breaker on the bottom.  For an outdoor panel entry, you *can't* invert the panel because that would defeat the water-resistant door!  So bottom-entry cables must come to the top and do a "180" to attach to the breaker.  Thus, they need lots of wire bending space.

Comment: the 2nd & 3rd paragraphs are really helpful for people who have read your answers and wondered _how_ to do what you usually recommend. Thanks!

Comment: Why you say wires coming in the top to go to bottom breakers, and wires coming in the bottom to go to top breakers ?   Just so there's plenty of extra wire if you need to move things around ?

Comment: Of course, the outdoor panel doesn't really have more space at bottom and sides - almost all the height difference is above the main breaker.

Comment: It seems odd that the ground bars are way up at the top, especially on the PNW one, since as you say, circuits cannot enter from the top.   The grounds definitely will not reach for the circuits that enter from the bottom.   I guess I have to wirenut extensions, or install a new ground bar at the bottom.  Or the controversial practice of landing grounds and neutrals onto the same bars (the ones the grounds can reach beside the breakers).

Comment: @Rusty When the bus is right where the cables enter, you have a lot of wires maneuvering to land on the bus.  That tends to make the area really congested.  Whereas a bunch of wires groomed into a bundle don't take much space at all, so it's not so bad to have opposite-end bars, on new construction.  You can always add accessory ground bars - what you can't do is put neutral on those.  Ground bars are rated for fault current not service current.

Comment: Understood, about the congestion.  As far as length, I either have to add extensions - for which I gather it's acceptable to extend several ground wires (theoretically all of them) with a single extension, as long as it's as thick as the thickest one being extended; or, add an accessory bar at the bottom or beside the breakers, or move the supplied ones (but it's interesting that the drawing for the indoor panels says the ground bars are moveable, but those in the outdoor panel are not ).

Comment: BTW, I thought it was an issue of some debate as to whether it's ok to have neutrals and grounds landing on the same bars.   My current home's panel - wired and inspected in 1988 - is done that way.   And from what I've read, some jurisdictions still consider it ok, although saying neutrals should not share screws with any other neutrals or grounds.

Comment: @RustyShackleford *Not a debate, just complicated lol*.... Neutrals are never allowed on ground bars because they're not rated for continuous current..... Grounds *are* allowed on *neutral* bars **in the main panel only** because there's a neutral-ground bond there anyway so it makes no difference. Some panels have only neutral bars.... Grounds can be as much as tripled-up on a lug (per labeling/instructions) but neutrals must always be solo.  .......... But these days a lot of installations are "meter-mains" where the main breaker is at the meter, and the panel is a subpanel. Separate there.

Comment: @Rusty your "understood..." comment sounds correct.  I would do accessory ground bars myself, but there's no rule against extending grounds with wire-nuts.

Comment: Ok thanks.   And I'm I right that installing a ground bar simply requires sheet-metal screws into the enclosure's back wall, relying on that for connectivity ?

Comment: @RustyShackleford No, you can't get ground connectivity from sheet metal screws.  You need a correctly tapped hole and fine machine screws with -32 or finer thread pitch for that.  However, the panel label will list some models of ground bar. If you buy those, they'll fit pre-drilled/tapped sites in the chassis.

Comment: Also (for another, outdoor, panel replacement I'm looking at) tempted to bring service in through "hub" at top of outdoor panel (less congestion at bottom where branch circuits come in). Would require U-shaped conduit from top of meter base.  RMC or IMC looks expensive, and difficult for a DIY'er (threading the ends); dunno how likely AHJ would be to allow PVC conduit - I'm sure it could be made rain-tight, and ground continuity handled with conductors, but who knows; lotta trouble to save a little congestion.

Comment: @RustyShackleford -- the issue with sheet metal screws is that they have a coarse thread, which means that they don't get enough threads into the metal to provide a good electrical connection (the rule is a minimum of 2 full threads engaged)

Comment: Thanks.   I am now considering using the 225-amp 42-space/64-circuit version of the panel (for the indoor application of my OP).   It is 39" tall, so only sacrifices 2" of top&bottom space (over my current 20-space one which is 30" tall).   Probably more spaces than I'll ever need, but what's the harm ?  Also, 225-amps might be nice, and the POCO tells me my feed will support that.